# Как составить хитрый POST запрос cURL?

Tags: curl, php

Всем привет.

И снова мои кривые руки привели меня сюда. В общих чертах. Появилась задача разработать скрипт, алгоритм работы:

1. Вход на сайт(простой и с прокси)
   -в моём случае нужно заходить именно с прокси.
2. Парсинг элемента формы
3. Отправка POST запроса на самого себя же,включающим в себя данные после парсинга.

В виде од это выглядит вот так:

```
$url='http://тарам пам пам.ru/poll/5697';
$proxy_addr='стоПятьСот:8080';
$head = array(
'Host: тарам пам пам.ru',
'User-Agent: и т.д
);
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_addr);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

В результате выполнения этого кода. скрипт под проксей заходит на сайт, и только тогда
может начинать парсить.Да еще это значение, которое парсит скрипт, меняется при каждом входе на сайт, поэтому все нужно сделать в одной curl сессии.
После парсинга мы получаем 1 параметр, который и надо отправить POST запросом. На этот же тарам пам пам.ру.
Можно ли еще раз вызвать:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Под открытой сессией $ch.
Или как лучше это оформить? 
Подскажите кто чем может. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё ребят разобрался! 
Теперь раскрою секрет скрипта=)
Я писал накрутчик опроса  для своего сайта на Drupal 7.
Было интересно как себя вела новая защита в 7 версии.